# Is it possible to import test cases from Excel to TFS?

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I need help in importing test cases from excel to TFS [Version 14.102.25423.0]. As we have to write thousands of old test cases in TFS which seems to be very time consuming task. 
I've already tried using- Test Case Migrator Plus. But its not working bcz of-TCMP has stopped working error. I'm unable to find solution for this error. Also there is no alternative I could find for same on Google.
I have also tried using Team Addin for excel but this gives option of importing Data from TFS to Excel but not vise versa.
So Plz let me know if anybody knows any solution or any otheralternative for getting this done.Thanks in Advance!
Note: I've Visual Studio 2015 installed on my VM with Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way  to import your test case back to TFS is: Import your test cases from web portal by **copy and save**.  Note you must switch to the grid view first.

[image]

For more details take a look at below two links:

- [Importing Test cases from Excel to TFS](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/14220/importing-test-cases-from-excel-to-tfs)
- [Add feature in TFS to export and import test case to and from TFS with steps,actions and expected result details](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/7076544-add-feature-in-tfs-to-export-and-import-test-case)

If you have multiple/thousands of test cases which need to upload. While TFS does not offer an out-of-the-box feature as a perfect solution. The 3rd-party tool *Test Case Migrator Plus* you are using seems only until 2013 version and there isn’t the version which supports TFS 2015.

You could still use the grid view, if you use three columns in Excel, you can even import many test cases into TFS at once. Besides depending on what you have as input, you can also do it with a bit of code, e.g. in C#. Just append some text, split columns by `\t` and rows by `\r\n`. Use `Clipboard.SetText()` and then paste in TFS.

---

There also has been a related user voice, you could vote up to get more attention, TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion:

> **Exporting Test Cases with Steps to Word/Excel**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/19582678-exporting-test-cases-with-steps-to-word-excel

Comment: Yeah it seems 'Test Case Migrator Plus' can not be used for my TFS version. So we have to manage with this work around only as suggested by you and in other posts, however with Grid limiting data to just 3 columns is a pain, anyways.. Thank you Patrick! Appreciated.

Comment: @SatyendraSharma We are sorry for bringing you trouble. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer which will also helps others in the community.